# Template Does not exist error while deploying on pythonanywhere

Tags: python, django, django-templates, pythonanywhere

I was trying to create a blog in my domain using django 1.9 and python 3.5 with virtual environment. So while deploying on pythonanywhere. I am able to render the html. Here is the traceback.

`Request Method: GET`
`Request URL: http://www.example.com/`

`Django Version: 1.9`
`Python Version: 3.5.2`
`Installed Applications:`

```
['django.contrib.admin', `     
` 'django.contrib.auth',   `   
 `'django.contrib.contenttypes',`        
 `'django.contrib.sessions',`     
 `'django.contrib.messages',`      
 `'django.contrib.staticfiles',`      
 `'blog']``
```

`Installed Middleware:`
`['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',`
 `'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',`
 `'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',`
 `'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',`
 `'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',`
 `'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',`
 `'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',`
 `'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']`

`Template loader postmortem`
`Django tried loading these templates, in this order:`

```
Using engine django:
* django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:       
/home/pdlsaroj22/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/blog/templates/blog/post/list.html(Source does not exist)
* django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: 
/home/pdlsaroj22/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/blog/templates/blog/post/list.html(Source does not exist)
* django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: 
/home/pdlsaroj22/myblog/mysite/blog/templates/blog/templates/blog/post/list.html (Source does not exist)

Using engine django:
* django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: 
/home/pdlsaroj22/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/blog/post_list.html (Source does not exist)
* django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: 
/home/pdlsaroj22/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/blog/post_list.html (Source does not exist)
* django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: 
/home/pdlsaroj22/myblog/mysite/blog/templates/blog/post_list.html (Source does not exist)
```

Traceback:

```
File "/home/pdlsaroj22/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
                     response = `self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "/home/pdlsaroj22/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
                     response = response.render()
File "/home/pdlsaroj22/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in render
             self.content = self.rendered_content
File "/home/pdlsaroj22/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in rendered_content
             template = self._resolve_template(self.template_name)
File "/home/pdlsaroj22/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in _resolve_template
             new_template = self.resolve_template(template)
File "/home/pdlsaroj22/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in resolve_template
             return select_template(template, using=self.using)
File "/home/pdlsaroj22/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in select_template
             raise TemplateDoesNotExist(', '.join(template_name_list), chain=chain)
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist at /
Exception Value: blog/templates/blog/post/list.html, blog/post_list.html
```

My views.py looks like this:

```
class PostListView(ListView):    
   queryset = Post.published.all()    
   context_object_name = 'posts'    
      paginate_by = 3    
      template_name = 'blog/templates/blog/post/list.html'
```

Comment: What are your TEMPLATES settings? It looks like you've hardcoded the dirs to your local home directory.

Comment: can you please show me your settinsg.py file

Comment: Also, what is the location of your list.html file ?

Answer (score 2):

If u have an app called blog (As registered in your settings.py), and you have APP_DIR set to true under template directories in settings.py, then chances are that you have a directory called templates in your blog app and another directory called blog within templates.

If that is the case, then `blog/templates/blog/post/list.html` should actually be written as: `post/list.html` provided you have a post directory in the blog directory of the blog app.

Answer (score 1):

you have to make folder named `"templates"` where `settingd.py` reside, and put your .html file in this template folder. and make changes in following `settings.py` file:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'), ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

And in your code do changes as following:

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    queryset = Post.published.all()
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 3
    template_name = 'list.html'
```

hope this answer help you.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to redirect to the correct template directory.
my templates was in the folder 'templates' in the root folder(the same folder containing manage.py).

It showed the same error with this setting:

```
'DIRS': ['templates'],
```

So, I changed it to this:

```
'DIRS': ['appointment/templates'],
```

And it worked!
btw, 'appointment' is the name of my project.

In pythonanywhere, you should prefix / with the name of your project, because that folder is your new home.